# jetty NPE at org.mortbay.start.Main.init(Main.java:465)

Tags: jetty

There is strange exception starting Jetty 6.1.21:

```
c:\TestJetty>java -jar start.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.init(Main.java:465)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:439)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Google suggest to add `-Djetty.home=.`. Jetty starts with this argument. But at other computers jetty starts even without this argument...
Looks very strange. All environment looks identical.
But...

Comment: You are not describing what is in the C:\TestJetty directory

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt TestJetty directory contains jetty server. It is usual jetty server version 6.1.21 as described without any specificity. I start it usual way as you can see. The feature of the problem is that jetty will not start with NPE if root directory contains file start.jar even without any content. No matter if os is Windows or Linux. It's a strange bug that I could not search in bug tracker or google. Moreover as you can see it's hard to guess that some file in other directory can be this exception cause. All similar questions I found has no adequate answers except "add -Djetty.home..."

Comment: Besides I found this bug rather fun. Ok, one more minus and I'll delete question )

Comment: @svaor line 465 of `org.mortbay.start.Main` reads `File file=new File(System.getProperty("jetty.home"));` so that explains why adding the `-Djetty.home=something` property on the command line resolves that issue. Could you try to launch jetty again with `-DDEBUG` argument (without `jetty.home` or `c:\start.jar` existing), which might show you why it's failing

Comment: @Alex Thanx for your interest in my question. This question already has answer. I've already found the cause: c:\start.jar is the cause of NPE when you start jetty from any other directory in disk c:. Jetty in debug mode shows that all related conditions from `start.config` (`jetty.home=[. / .. / home/jetty / /C:/jetty / .]`) fail because first condition (`jetty.home=. ! exists $(jetty.home)/start.jar`) fails. First condition fails because `$(jetty.home)/start.jar` is interepted as `/start.jar` at first iteration and points to current disk root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c:\TestJetty>echo 1 > c:\start.jar

c:\TestJetty>java -jar start.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.init(Main.java:465)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:439)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)

c:\TestJetty>rm c:\start.jar

c:\TestJetty>java -jar start.jar
2013-04-19 18:03:12.989::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
...
```

Comment: Is this answer supposed to mean anything?!

Comment: @carlspring Do you think - should jetty run from c:\SomeDir if root directory (c:\) contains file start.jar?.. I showed this case in my answer. Check it if you want. I spent some time googling this problem and searching bug in jetty project code. I hope this answer save this time for somebody else.

Comment: My apologies, but your answer contains no actual explanation of what you're doing and what you're showing as a list of commands and output makes no real sense. Articulate your question first. Then describe the steps in your answer. What you've shown and are doing in the above really means nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Lets see what is going on ...

First, my environment

```
C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

C:\>systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

C:\jetty-6.1.21>java -version
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode, sharing)


C:\jetty-6.1.21>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8CF-820B

 Directory of C:\jetty-6.1.21

04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          .
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          bin
04/19/2013  11:50 AM    <DIR>          contexts
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          contrib
04/19/2013  11:50 AM    <DIR>          distribution
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          etc
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          examples
04/19/2013  11:50 AM    <DIR>          extras
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          javadoc
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          jxr
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          lib
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          LICENSES
09/21/2009  11:07 PM    <DIR>          logs
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          modules
09/21/2009  11:07 PM             1,621 NOTICE.txt
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          patches
09/22/2009  12:17 AM             9,170 pom.xml
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          project-website
09/21/2009  11:07 PM             4,253 README.txt
04/19/2013  11:51 AM    <DIR>          resources
09/22/2009  04:44 PM            17,239 start.jar
09/21/2009  11:07 PM           161,333 VERSION.txt
04/19/2013  11:50 AM    <DIR>          webapps
               5 File(s)        193,616 bytes
              19 Dir(s)  315,649,884,160 bytes free
```

Next, lets try it normally ...

```
C:\jetty-6.1.21>java -jar start.jar
2013-04-19 11:54:10.334::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2013-04-19 11:54:11.019::INFO:  jetty-6.1.21
2013-04-19 11:54:11.133::INFO:  Deploy C:\jetty-6.1.21\contexts\test.xml -> org.
mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@19616c7{/,C:\jetty-6.1.21/webapps/test}
2013-04-19 11:54:11.171::INFO:  Deploy C:\jetty-6.1.21\contexts\javadoc.xml -> o
rg.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler@3bb2b8{/javadoc,file:/C:/jetty-6.1.21/ja
vadoc/}
2013-04-19 11:54:11.287::INFO:  Deploy C:\jetty-6.1.21\contexts\test-jndi.xml ->
 org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@1df38fd{/test-jndi,C:\jetty-6.1.21/conte
xts/test-jndi.d}
```

It works as expected.

Lets introduce the wrinkle of the existence of `C:\start.jar`

```
C:\>dir *.jar
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8CF-820B

 Directory of C:\

04/19/2013  12:15 PM                 1 start.jar
               1 File(s)              1 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  315,647,086,592 bytes free

C:\jetty-6.1.21>java -jar start.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.init(Main.java:465)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:439)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Yup, that isn't correct behavior.  Lets see what jetty thinks is going on ...

```
C:\jetty-6.1.21>java -DDEBUG -jar start.jar
config=org/mortbay/start/start.config
T $(jetty.class.path).path                         always
F $(jetty.lib)/**                                  exists $(jetty.lib)
F jetty.home=.                                     ! exists $(jetty.home)/start.jar
F jetty.home=..                                    ! exists $(jetty.home)/start.jar
F jetty.home=/home/jetty                           ! exists $(jetty.home)/start.jar
F jetty.home=/C:/jetty                             ! exists $(jetty.home)/start.jar
F jetty.home=.                                     ! exists $(jetty.home)/start.jar
T org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.class
  CLASS=org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration
T $(start.class).class
T $(jetty.home)/etc/jetty.xml                      nargs == 0
  ARGS+=\etc\jetty.xml
T $(jetty.home)/lib/*                              always
T $(jetty.home)/lib/jsp-2.1/*                      java >= 1.5
T $(jetty.home)/lib/jsp-2.0/*                      ! available org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
T $(jetty.home)/lib/management/*
F $(jetty.home)/lib/management/mx4j/*              java < 1.5
T $(jetty.home)/lib/naming/*
T $(jetty.home)/lib/plus/*
T $(jetty.home)/lib/xbean/*
T $(jetty.home)/lib/wadi/*
T $(jetty.home)/lib/grizzly/*
T $(jetty.home)/lib/annotations/*                  java >= 1.5

T $(jetty.home)/lib/jre1.5/**                      java >= 1.5
T $(jetty.home)/lib/ext/**                        always
T /usr/share/java/ant.jar                          ! available org.apache.tools.ant.Main
T $(jetty.home)/resources/
  !C:\resources
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.init(Main.java:465)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:439)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Yup, every test for `$(jetty.home)` returns `F` (False)

You seem to have found a bug in `org.mortbay.start.Main` (not the `start.config`).

Unfortunately, this Jetty 6 bug will not be fixed, as Jetty 6 has been end of life'd years ago.

Lets see if this bug exist in Jetty 7, 8, or 9?

```
C:\jetty-distribution-7.6.10.v20130312>java -jar start.jar
2013-04-19 12:21:33.910:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.10.v20130312
2013-04-19 12:21:33.947:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\jet
ty-distribution-7.6.10.v20130312\webapps at interval 1
2013-04-19 12:21:33.956:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\jetty-d
istribution-7.6.10.v20130312\webapps\spdy.war
2013-04-19 12:21:34.078:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/C:/jetty
-distribution-7.6.10.v20130312/webapps/spdy.war!/ to C:\Users\joakim\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-spdy.war-_spdy-any-\webapp

C:\jetty-distribution-8.1.10.v20130312>java -jar start.jar
2013-04-19 12:21:46.946:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
2013-04-19 12:21:46.984:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\jet
ty-distribution-8.1.10.v20130312\webapps at interval 1
2013-04-19 12:21:46.995:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\jetty-d
istribution-8.1.10.v20130312\webapps\spdy.war
2013-04-19 12:21:47.115:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/C:/jetty
-distribution-8.1.10.v20130312/webapps/spdy.war!/ to C:\Users\joakim\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-spdy.war-_spdy-any-\webapp

C:\jetty-distribution-9.0.2.v20130417>java -jar start.jar
2013-04-19 12:22:19.127:WARN::main: test-realm is deployed. DO NOT USE IN PRODUC
TION!
2013-04-19 12:22:19.132:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.2.v20130417
2013-04-19 12:22:19.214:INFO:oejs.AbstractNCSARequestLog:main: Opened C:\jetty-d
istribution-9.0.2.v20130417\logs\2013_04_19.request.log
2013-04-19 12:22:19.251:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor
[file:/C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.2.v20130417/webapps/] at interval 1
2013-04-19 12:22:19.669:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: started o.e.j.w.WebAppCo
ntext@3e125554{/,file:/C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.2.v20130417/webapps/ROOT/,AVAIL
ABLE}{C:\jetty-distribution-9.0.2.v20130417\webapps\ROOT}
2013-04-19 12:22:19.703:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: started o.e.j.s.h.Contex
tHandler@7ffa129b{/javadoc,file:/C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.2.v20130417/javadoc,A
VAILABLE}
```

Not present in Jetty 7, 8, or 9.

Even testing early versions of Jetty 7.0.0 milestones shows that this bug is not present on any of 124 releases of Jetty since Jetty 6.1.26.

Consider upgrading.

Comment: Thnxs for detailed answer. It's realy that I mean [creating and answering own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Unfortunately my answer was unclear. So, +1 for your one ;)